# A question about countability of a set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $\left\{ x_\alpha : \alpha \in \mathscr{A}\right\} \subset (0, + \infty ) $ be a set of positive real numbers such that for every countable subcollection $ \left\{ x_{\alpha_n} \right\} $ of distinct points it holds $ x_{\alpha_n} \rightarrow 0 $. Then $ \mathscr{A} $ is a countable set. \

I think that this statement is true. How can i prove it? (if it is true)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\epsilon>0$ the set $A_\epsilon:=\{x_\alpha\mid x_\alpha>\epsilon\}$ must be finite as otherwise we'd find a countable subcollection with limit $\ge\epsilon$. Therefore
$$\{x_\alpha\mid \alpha\in\mathscr A\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_{\frac1n}$$
is the countable union of finite sets, hence countable.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: for each $n$, there are only finitely many $x \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $|x| \geq \frac{1}{n}$ -- otherwise you can easily find a sequence in $\mathcal{A}$ that does not converge to 0.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $X$ denote this collection. Prove that for every $n\in\Bbb N$, $X\cap\left(\frac1n,+\infty\right)$ must be finite.